# How to select multiple values from VS Code choice-type snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, code-snippets

I use VS Code and Markdown to journal and track things. The following markdown snippet is an example of using `choice`-type variables in a snippet.

**How would I select multiple `TOOLS` from the choice below?**
As soon as I choose 1 option, I'm taken to `$0`.

```
"Context": {
            "prefix": "scontext",
            "body": [
                "- **TYPE:**            ${1|COMMS,SUPPORT,RESEARCH,MEETING,DEVELOPMENT,TESTING,VALIDATION,PROJECT MGMT,CONSULTING,DOCUMENTATION,ADMINISTRATION,TRAINING,BREAK|}",
                "- **PROJECT:**         ${2|Project1,Project2,Project3|}",
                "- **TOOLS:**           ${3|Python,Azure Storage,Azure Function,Azure Key Vault,Etc.|}",
                "- **START:**           ${CURRENT_YEAR}-${CURRENT_MONTH}-${CURRENT_DATE}T${CURRENT_HOUR}:${CURRENT_MINUTE}:${CURRENT_SECOND}-08:00",
                "- **END:**             ",
                "- **DURATION:**        ",
                "- **NOTES:**",
                "  - $0",
                "---"
            ],
            "description": "New context"
        },
```